# variable named struct in go

Tags: go, struct

how can i get this output?

```
type datas struct {
    age int
    height int
    weight int
}
func main(){
    var age := 5
    var height := 10
    var weight := 15
    namelist := []string{"b", "c", "d"}
    for count, a := range namelist {
        a := datas{age+count,height+count,weight+count}
    //Expected Output: b{6,11,16} , c{7,12,17}, d{8,13,18}
    }
}
```

I can't find anything about this case and I guess this feature is not included. Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: Put these structs in an array or a map (if you really want to address them by name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, you can put your data on a map with the key name

```
type datas struct {
    age int
    height int
    weight int
}
func main(){
    structMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    age := 5
    height := 10
    weight := 15
    namelist := []string{"b", "c", "d"}
    for count, val := range namelist {
        count = count + 1 // this is due to your expected output
        out := datas{age+count,height+count,weight+count}
        structMap[val] = out
    }

    fmt.Println(structMap)
    // output: map[b:{6 11 16} c:{7 12 17} d:{8 13 18}]
}
```